# Google Pub/Sub seems to lose messages on heavy load in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, locking, google-cloud-pubsub

Google Pub/Sub using

```
pubsub_v1.PublisherClient
```

seem to lose a few messages on heavy load

```
self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials)

try:
    topic_path = self._get_topic_path(topic)
            
    data = bytes(self._data, "utf-8")

    future = self.publisher.publish(topic_path, data)

    result = future.result()

    if result is None:
        code = f"{future._exception.code}"
        raise Exception(code, future._exception.message)

    return result

except Exception as e:
     raise Exception(400, e.args[0])
```

I've used Newman to test our Data and Analytics Pipeline with running 3 Batch Jobs separately with 10,000 messages each.

The above python code is wrapped with a acquire lock and a release lock.

Running the above several times accounted for about 11 events to be "lost"

There is a Pub/Sub Subscription that writes to BigQuery dataset Table

Comment: What's an "heavy load" for you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, we have an existing Data Pipeline where we are experiencing about 80% data loss.

We have rewritten the Data Pipeline and have been testing it using Newman. "Heavy Load" therefore, is pushing as many messages as possible through the new Data Pipeline without duplicates, loss messages, and failures.

Comment: My question was about your message per second that you expect. You mention 10k messages, it's few for PubSub, which is able to manage up to 1M per second. Therefore, I strongly recommend checking your code and be sure that it's not a bug in things that you wrote. I often saw questions that doubt about Google Cloud reliability and every time it was  user side issue. Additional remarks, if you have a heavy load, you should also reconsider Python language.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I've checked the code. It would perfectly when running 1 (10,000) batch at a time. Running more than 1 causes losses.

I'm not sure where the problem is since once the message is published, it is configured to immediately write it to a BigQuery table.

In  Python, how does one check whether a published message has failed? Is the code above ok?